# An error in the derivation of the energy of state for independent indistinguishable molecules (ideal gas law)

Tags: thermodynamics

I want to ask a question about the derivation of the partial gas law that I covered today.

Our lecturer spoke about the Helmhotz free energy that can be expressed (when measured relative to the ground state)

$$A = A(0) - kTlnQ$$

and given that

$$Q = \frac{q^N}{N!}$$

$$q = \frac{V}{ʌ^3}$$

$$P = \frac{\partial A}{\partial V}_T$$

we can evaluate P:

$$= \frac{kT}{Q} \left (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial V} \right)_T$$
$$= N! \frac{kT}{q^N} \left (\frac{\frac{\partial q^N}{N!}}{\partial V} \right)_T$$
$$=\frac{kT}{q^N}\left (\frac{\partial q^N}{\partial V} \right)_T$$
$$= \frac{kT}{q^N}\left (\frac{\partial q^N}{\partial q} \frac{\partial q}{\partial V} \right)_T $$
$$= \frac{kTq^{N-1}}{q^N}\left (\frac{\partial q}{\partial V} \right)_T $$

Up to this point, there is no presence of N.

I expected the next line to be

$$\frac{kT}{q} \left (\frac{\partial q}{\partial V} \right)_T $$

and with the substitution of $q$ as defined above this proceeds to be

$$\frac{kT}{q} \left (\frac{\partial \frac{V}{ʌ^3}}{dV}\right)_T $$

However, the lecturer continues the proof as follows

$$= \frac{NkTʌ^3}{V}\left (\frac{\partial \frac{V}{ʌ^3}}{dV}\right)_T$$

and I'm struggling to understand where the N returns into the proof in this line.

This evidently continues to

$$ = \frac{NkT}{V}$$
$$ = \frac{nRT}{V}$$

which is the ideal gas law, derived from first principles.

but I'm confused about the $N$ term.
How does the $N$ term return to the line specified above?

Answer (score 0):

The chain rule result is incorrect. 
It should be:

$$= \frac{NkTq^{N-1}}{q^N}\left (\frac{\partial q}{\partial V} \right)_T $$